# What is a reason that LINQ to SQL wouldn't generate a collection based on a relationship?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a relationship between two entities (e1 and e2) and e1 has a collection of e2, however I have a similar relationship set up between (e2 and e3), yet e2 does not contain a collection of e3's, any reason why this would happen? Anything I can post to make this easier to figure out?

Edit: I just noticed that the relationship between e1 and e2 is solid and between e2 and e3 is dotted, what causes that? Is it related?

Comment: did you get it working, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

**Using this setup, everything worked.**

*1) LINQ to SQL Query, 2) DB Tables, 3) LINQ to SQL Data Model in VS.NET 2008*

**1 - LINQ to SQL Query**

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var results = from threes in db.tableThrees
    join twos in db.tableTwos on threes.fk_tableTwo equals twos.id
    join ones in db.tableOnes on twos.fk_tableOne equals ones.id
    select new { ones, twos, threes };
```

**2 - Database Scripts**

```
--Table One
CREATE TABLE tableOne(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tableOne] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( [id] ASC ) WITH ( 
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
     STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY];

--Table Two
CREATE TABLE tableTwo(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
    [fk_tableOne] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tableTwo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( [id] ASC ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY];

ALTER TABLE tableTwo WITH CHECK     
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tableTwo_tableOne]   
    FOREIGN KEY([fk_tableOne])
    REFERENCES tableOne ([id]);

ALTER TABLE tableTwo CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tableTwo_tableOne];


--Table Three
CREATE TABLE tableThree(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [fk_tableTwo] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tableThree] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([id] ASC ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY];

ALTER TABLE tableThree WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tableThree_tableTwo] 
    FOREIGN KEY([fk_tableTwo])
    REFERENCES tableTwo ([id]);

ALTER TABLE tableThree CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tableThree_tableTwo];
```

**3 - LINQ to SQL Data Model in Visual Studio**

[alt text http://i478.photobucket.com/albums/rr148/KyleLanser/ThreeLevelHierarchy.png](http://i478.photobucket.com/albums/rr148/KyleLanser/ThreeLevelHierarchy.png)

Answer (score 0):

the FK_Contraints are set up like this:

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e2] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_e2_e1] FOREIGN KEY([E1Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[e1] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e3] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_e3_e2] FOREIGN KEY([E2Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[e2] ([Id])

is this what you were asking for?